# Get Reference to an object from external application

Tags: vb.net

Hi all
I have handle of a usercontrol on external application in vb.net.
I know class type of that user control.
I want to get refrence to that object to check some properties of that object.
Is it possible and how?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I hope I do understand your question right...

You may try to insert a reference to your library (I assume your userControl is in this library). As a prerequisite this external application must be written in .Net or have some kind auf COM interface!

Then you may try to access the userControl class by

```
NAMESPACE.CLASS myReference = new NAMESPACE.CLASS();
```

hth

Comment: thanks dear
Let me add some more information on this issue.
I can get handle of some controls on a .net application that is running.
Now I want to access to object of one of these controls to read some properties. but not text of that control. but a public property of that class.
All is done in another application written in vb.net.
I don't want to create new instance of that class. I want to access to exactly that object reference and I only have a handle (through API) of that control.

Any idea?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean. If you have a handle to that control, you do already have some kind of reference to an object... what kind of API do you mean. Perhaps Reflection may be of some use... ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183(v=vs.80).aspx ) Can you post your source code pls?!

Answer (score 0):

You can get some info by using interop, with some functions like [GetWindowText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633520.aspx) and [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950.aspx), however this won't allow you to get all properties, and won't work on every type of application (WPF or Java come to mind).

Comment: thanks dear
Let add some more information on this issue.
I can get handle of some controls on a .net application that is running.
Now I want to access to object of one of these controls to read some properties. but not text of that control. but a public property of that class.
All is done in another application written in vb.net.
Any idea?

Answer (score -1):

The Control Class has a method FromHandle:

```
Dim myCtrl As knownType = Control.FromHandle(knownHandle)
'then get the known property using Reflection
Dim oProp As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo = myCtrl.GetType.GetProperty("KnownProperty")
Dim oValue As Object = oProp.GetValue(myCtrl, Nothing)
'or directly:
Dim oValueD as Object = myCtrl.knownProperty
```

I don't know if it works between processes.